Spring Boot Exception Handler not detecting Exceptions inside SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl class
I'm having class that implements SAMLUserDetailsService and inside it there's some business logic of parsing user. Wherever exception is thrown inside that class I get Whitelable error page because my custom exception handler is not detecting, and thus handling, that exception.
It works in other places, on other controllers.
SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl implements SAMLUserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;
    private final OibService oibService;

    @Override
    public Object loadUserBySAML(SAMLCredential credential) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user;
    //Do some stuff
    if(personIdentifier != null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not legal");
    }
    return new Authentication(credential, user);
  }
}

Global exception handler
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApiExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { IllegalArgumentException.class, IllegalStateException.class, ParseException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleBadRequestExceptions(Exception e) {
        HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        log.error("BAD_REQUEST", e);
        ApiException apiException = new ApiException(e.getMessage(), httpStatus, ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Z")));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiException, httpStatus);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { Exception.class })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllOtherExceptions(Exception e) {
        HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        log.error("INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR:", e);
        ApiException apiException = new ApiException(e.getMessage(), httpStatus, ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Z")));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiException, httpStatus);
    }
}


Perhaps spring-security is catching the IllegalArgumentException, and wrapping it another exception such as an AuthenticationException.  Try debugging, and follow that throw to see how spring-security handles it.

Remove the handler and try to see which error you are getting on client side.
Handle that exception.
Also, it would be better to use a custom exception (perhaps NullPersonIdentifierException) rather than IllegalArgumentException.

most likely because the loadUserBySAML is thrown in a filter, ControllerAdvices are invoked in all code after filters.

@Toerktumlare I think your comment is most likely to be true because I've tried all sorts of things like creating custom exception ForbiddenException and creating all bunch of @ExceptionHandlers for every possible error in case it catches its wrapped type or it gets casted somehow, but no luck. Now what I end up doing is handling Whitelabel error in separate controller but that's just to ugly. Another thing that I can think of is instead of throwing error, doing restTemplate call to some controller with all error info that I would send to frontend. Is there more elegant way to handle this?

you have provided way to little information in your question to be able to answer this. We have no idea where the function "loadUserBySAML " is invoked, you have provided no HttpSecurity configuration, no example request, no debug logs with full stacktraces. I suggest you do some studying read the architecture of spring security https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-filters-review how filters work and how exceptions in filters are handled.

then Then architecture of authentication https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html then update your question with relevant debug logs, stacktrace etc. etc then a more elegant way can be suggested
